# Minimise Multivariate Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $x$ be a positive integer, and $a,b,c\in [0,1]$. We want to find a closed-form expression for the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ in terms of $x$ for which the following function is minimised.

Function:
\begin{align*}
x\left[\sqrt{(1-a)^2+(1-b)^2+c^2+(x-1)(a^2+b^2)}\nonumber\\~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+\sqrt{a^2+(1-b)^2+(1-c)^2+(x-1)(a^2+b^2)}~\right].
\end{align*}

Does a closed-form solution always exist? How should one approach these kind of questions?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The $[$ denotes some integer part?

Comment: No, they are just brackets.

Comment: And what about the first star?

Comment: x * y = xy, product of x and y. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh, so you want to minimize $f(a,b,c) = x(\left[\sqrt{(1-a)^2+(1-b)^2+c^2+(x-1)(a^2+b^2)}+\sqrt{a^2+(1-b)^2+(1-c)^2+(x-1)(a^2+b^2)}~\right])$.

Comment: Yes, and solve for a,b and c in terms of x.

Answer (score 0):

Using numerical optimization for the very first values of $x$, we can conjecture that, at the minimum $b=\frac 1 x$.

Assuming that this is true, we are left with the problem of minimizing with respect to $a$ and $c$ the function
$$x \left(\sqrt{a^2 x-2 a+c^2-\frac{1}{x}+2}+\sqrt{a^2 x+c^2-2 c-\frac{1}{x}+2}\right)$$

Repeating the process, it seems that, as soon as $x>1$, $c$ is a constant numerically equal to $0.5857864375$ which looks like $(2-\sqrt 2)$. If this is true, then, the problem reduces to
$$x \left(\sqrt{a^2 x-\frac{1}{x}-2 \sqrt{2}+4}+\sqrt{a^2 x-2 a-\frac{1}{x}-4
   \sqrt{2}+8}\right)$$

Computing the derivative of the above is possible but setting it equal to zero leads to a monster.

So, continuing and  *observing*, we can conjecture that $a=\frac k x$ where $k\sim 0.4142135$ which looks very much like $(\sqrt 2-1)$.

To summarize
$$\color{red} {a=\frac {\sqrt 2-1} x \qquad\qquad b=\frac 1 x \qquad\qquad c=2-\sqrt 2}$$ and the minimum value of the function is
$$\color{blue} {\sqrt{2 \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)x(x\sqrt 2-1)}}$$

We do not need $x$ to be an integer. Computing for $x=e\pi$, the minimum is attained for
$$a=0.048504268539674619 \qquad b=0.11709966300008920 \qquad c=0.58578643758640058$$ and the minimum value is $21.371561345127076$.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. I was trying along similar lines. The trouble is that I need to prove formally that these values of a, b and c indeed minimises the expression. That is where I don't have much clue.